# REST,API and Php for searching online with android app

Tags: php, android

I have an android app I accept a keyword to be searched,And I want to search ebay (an example) like searching for "Samsung S3" and displaying the values back in my app
I dont know how to go about this,Ive been told about REST,Php and APIs

Do I need to communicate with the database since Im not adding anything
And is there a way to make an API only in php,not using REST

I really have no experience of this..Im not trying to solicit a debate,I just want a very simple answer.So I will know which aspect I will start with.Thanks for ur support in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. If the website in question (eBay) has an HTTP API for search, you don't need PHP or a database at all. You simply need to make a request to the API from the Android app itself. The eBay search API is documented at http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/Concepts/FindingAPIGuide.html

If there's no API, the website will probably have restrictions on how you can use their data.

Comment: Im assuming the website is mine,Do I need to communicate with the Php server alone or REST API

Comment: The PHP server should not be accessed by your Android app directly. That's the entire point of creating an API. You should create a REST endpoint which your app can access at website.com/api/search?q=samsung+s3, and which returns the search results in a suitable format.

Comment: Ok,Thanks but
1)Is the REST actually written in php
2) Is the REST the job of a php developer or mine as an android application writer,I was told Im only suppose to focus on parsing the json and xml
3)Is the REST to be added to the android application as a file or its just a one-liner I will add to my app in the HTTPurlcomnection request


Thank you in advance Osiris

Comment: REST is not a program. It is a way of implementing the API, and will be done in PHP or whatever language you use on your server (Ruby/Python etc), and is the job of the PHP developer. In the Android app, you will only have to worry about sending the HTTP request and parse the returned json or xml. 
Also, you should accept/upvote an answer that you think has helped you.

Comment: So I'll just worry about sending the HTTP request to the "http://mysite.com/search.php" and parse the json it returns to me...Thank you very much,Id already set out on learning php(but now a limited part) God bless